# How to zero out user data in memory (RAM) of WKWebView after dealloc

Tags: ios, security, heap-memory, wkwebview

I would like iOS to zero out user sensitive data from memory (specifically username/password entered in HTML pages) of WKWebView once the user is done with it.

Below project depicts the difference in the memory management of WKWebView & UITextField -

https://github.com/iosappdeveloper/CleanMemoryCheck.git

1. In the case of UITextField (a native control), the system automatically zeros out memory once `UITextField` object is deallocated -

As a user, when I input text (e.g. *tingtong*) in `UITextField` and then as Xcode developer, I pause Xcode to locate the memory address. (notice first `cstr_refs` call below) 
However, once UITextField is deallocated (user pop out of the screen), the developer is not able to locate the memory for same user text. (second `cstr_refs` call below)

[image: Pause and check in Xcode command line]

2. In the case of `WKWebView`, the system does not zero out memory after `WKWebView` is deallocated -

As a developer, I'm able to locate the memory of user input text (i.e. username/password on google.com login) EVEN after WKWebView is deallocated (pop out of the screen).

Is there any explicit API or project setting that can help me achieve the same in WKWebView managed data?

Comment: This is almost certainly impossible to achieve with WKWebView, beyond marking the field as `input=password`. WKWebView does not exist in your process space.

Comment: Are you sure your `WKWebView` gets really deallocated? Perhaps something is holding its reference. A common mistake is when a vc containing wkwebview is a delegate of `wkwebview.userContentController` which will lead to retain cycle if there's no cleanup code.

Comment: WKWebView is getting deallocated (I shared the link of sample app code above). Actually the web caches are stored in `WKWebsiteDataStore` which is a singleton object. I tried calling `removeData(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes(), modifiedSince: Date.distantPast)` but my understanding is that it does not zero out the memory.

Comment: Although webview is deallocated, the `UIProcess` that was associated with it, still exists, because, by default, `WKWebView` uses the shared process pool. Try to provide your own process pool to `WKWebViewConfiguration`, and deallocate it together with the web view. I'm only guessing here. If that does not help, you can consult source code of WKWebView to see what may trigger memory cleanup, it's open.

Comment: Still no solution.
I tried creating `WKWebView` instance by giving it a new `WKWebViewConfiguration` instance created with `WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistent()` (new instance of data store / private browsing) and new `WKProcessPool` object but I still see user entered data in the web page after user navigates out of `WKWebView` (deinit).